# Ubuntu doesn't see my USB hard drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I have a 500 gb USB hard drive NTFS partitioned that worked till yesterday, but today it doesn't work at all. It doesn't show up on my Ubuntu machine, now in Windows XP or Windows 7, I tried several USB cables and ports, but the results are the same. When I plug it in the light goes on and the disk spins, so I know it "works", but it doesn't show up in gparted, fdisk or lsusb. This is the result of `dmesg | grep -i usb`:

```
vito@N76-ubuntu-vito:~$ dmesg | grep -i usb
[    1.212416] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.212424] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.212440] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.565462] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.565533] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.584213] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.584320] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.584426] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.604199] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.604296] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.604341] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.604351] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.604457] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.604700] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.604787] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.604863] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.640245] usbcore: registered new interface driver libusual
[    1.896080] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    2.028888] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.140044] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci_hcd
[    2.272299] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.439778] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.461930] usb 3-1: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.467776] input: Logitech USB Laser Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input4
[    2.467859] generic-usb 0003:046D:C062.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB Laser Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[    2.467867] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.467868] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.531932] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci_hcd
[    2.695682] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[   10.443457] Bluetooth: Generic Bluetooth USB driver ver 0.6
[   10.443487] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   10.898016] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device ASUS USB2.0 Webcam (1bcf:2883)
[   10.915702] input: ASUS USB2.0 Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/input/input5
[   10.915750] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   10.915751] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   11.077666] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   11.297581] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   11.499244] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
```

There's a really important backup on this hard drive and it's crucial for me to retrieve it, no matter what. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you dropped the disk or in any other way gave it a heavy impact, if you did the lens might be damaged, you would hear the disk spinning but it couldnt read it and thus doesnt show up in gparted.

just an idea, apart from that i have no idea why it wouldnt show up.
anyway, good luck i hope you find a way to acces your backup

Comment: That's probably it: the disk is broken. I opened it and plugged the disk into my notebook, but it still can't be read, so I gave up. I'll tryu to retrieve the backup through a recovery disk company.